# Change language on the dropdown list by setting and getting cookie in Laravel?

Tags: jquery, laravel, cookies, laravel-4, controller

I'm trying to change language in Laravel through a dropdown on the view page. After I select the language on the dropdown, I want to set the cookie and pass that cookie value to App::setLocale() in the LanguageController.
There's two things not working right now:

1. The link_to_route doesn't trigger anything
2. Cookie::get('lang') is always NULL, so the value is not passed to 
   App::setLocale();

**View**

```
<select id="dropdownLang">
    <option value="">Change Language</option>
    <option value="en"><?php echo link_to_route('language.lang', 'English', array('en'));?></option>
    <option value="sp">?php echo link_to_route('language.lang', 'Spanish', array('sp'));?></option>
</select>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('language/{lang}', ['as' => 'language.lang', 'uses' => 'LanguageController@lang']);
```

**Controller**

```
class LanguageController {

   public function __construct() {
      App::setLocale(Cookie::get('lang'));
      var_dump(Cookie::get('lang'));
   }

   public function lang($lang) {
      Cookie::forever('lang', $lang);

      return Redirect::back();
   }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to set language preferences in a cookie? What happens after the session ends?

Comment: `language.lange` you have a typo here.

Comment: @SasankaPanguluri - Thanks I changed the typo. If the session ends, they should be logged out and be brought to the login page. I want to set it as a cookie, so next time when they visit, the language they set before will be still there.

Comment: I would rather think it should be inserted into your database ( otherwise it will disappear after clearing cookies)

Comment: Setting locale in controller will not work. You need to use a middleware

Comment: You could put the selected locale in the cookies like you are doing in `public function lang($lang)`  then you fetch the cookie in a middle ware and set your locale. You middleware must run on each request. This is because Laravel does not store locale in session hence you must set locale on each request